# How to delete only tables in kdb?

Tags: kdb

say:

```
q) \a .x
`a`b

q) \f .x
`f1`f2
```

I need to delete only the tables a and b but not the functions. Now in this case, I can simply say `` delete a,b from `.x `` but is there a way to functionalize this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following.

```
q)tables[]  /get list of tables in current namespace
`table1`table2`table3..

q)parse"delete table1 from `."   /get the parse tree - needed to functionalise

q)![`.;();0b;tables[]]  /combine to delete only tables
`.
q)tables[]
`symbol$()
```

using namespaces

```
q)tables `.b
`table3`table4`table5
q){![x;();0b;tables x]} `.b
`.b
q)tables `.b
`symbol$()
```

Hope this helps

Connor